# Process.Start permissions - doesn't get executed on iis7 server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have a website (asp.net mvc) that uses asp.net impersonation, i imperonsate an administrator user using the web.config element:

1. I try to execute a process through Process.start (i tried to start a .bat file).
2. I enabled interaction with desktop for iis admin service.
3. I get no error, but nothing is really done. when i execute the .bat file locally- ot works perfectly.

Comment: IIRC "Interact with desktop" was dropped a while back.

Comment: Did you check the Event Log using eventvwr? I have run into problems in the past with this and usually when nothing seems to happen, an event was logged there.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem in using Foxit Reader (to print PDFs silently) via IIS; this works fine through Visual Studio 2010 when I run it, but fails miserably when running through IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you have a UAC problem try turning it off as a first stop...

http://www.petri.co.il/disable_uac_in_windows_vista.htm

let me know how you get on...

Answer (score 0):

Try to start your tools in "As Administrator" mode. (Right mouse click on short cut).