# Access denied when accessing powershell in webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

1. Below is my powershell script:

   ```
   #Accept input parameters  
   Param(  
       [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]  
       [string] $Office365Username,  
       [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]  
       [string] $Office365Password,
       [string]$GroupName
   )

   #Remove all existing Powershell sessions  
   Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession   

   #Did they provide creds?  If not, ask them for it.
   if (([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Office365Username) -eq $false) -and ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Office365Password) -eq $false))
   {

       $SecureOffice365Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Office365Password -Force      

       #Build credentials object  
       $Office365Credentials  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Office365Username, $SecureOffice365Password  
   }
   else
   {   
       #Build credentials object  
       $Office365Credentials  = Get-Credential
   }

   #Create remote Powershell session  
   $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Office365Credentials -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

   #Import the session  
   Import-PSSession $Session
   #cmds

   $result=Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited  
   return  $result
   #Clean up session  
   Remove-PSSession $Session
   ```
2. Below is my C# code

   ```
    public string GetAllGroups()
        {
            int count = 1;
            string getDListScript = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\O365Service\Scripts\GetDList.ps1";

            string userName = "j*****";
            string password = "****";
            try
            {
                using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    runSpace.Open();
                    ps.Runspace = runSpace;

                    ps.AddCommand(getDListScript).AddParameter("Office365Username", userName).AddParameter("Office365Password", password);
                    //IAsyncResult async = ps.BeginInvoke();
                    //StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                 var   results = ps.Invoke();
                 PSDataCollection<ErrorRecord> errors = ps.Streams.Error;
                 if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
                 {
                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                     foreach (ErrorRecord err in errors)
                     {
                         sb.Append(err.ToString());
                     }
                     System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\RestService\bin\err.text", sb.ToString());
                 }

                 count = results.Count;


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            return count.ToString();
   ```

   }

When i am executing the C# code on server from Console application it is working fine but when i am executing it from Webservice it is giving me the below exception

> [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server
> outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access
> is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
> Help topic.Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The
> argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try
> running the command again.The term 'Get-DistributionGroup' is not
> recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
> verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have set execution policy to unrestricted of the server.

Comment: Configure the webservice user as an admin user. Basically, if it is an IIS web service, setup the application pool with an admin user.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath - if this is an internet facing machine and site then that's a very bad idea. For things that need elevated rights you should sandbox such functionality in a separate process such as a windows service.

Comment: @Kev agreed. We need this information in that case

Comment: IIS does not allow you to run Windows processing for security reasons. maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414514/iis7-does-not-start-my-exe-file-by-process-start) can help you.

Comment: Add transcription and debugging to your PS script:
`try {Stop-Transcript} catch {};
$pref = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Continue;
$VerbosePreference = $pref;
$DebugPreference = $pref;
$InformationPreference = $pref;
$WarningPreference = $pref;
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\LOG\pstest_$([DateTimeOffset]::Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()).log.txt" -EA Stop;`. Use `-AllowClobber` on `Import-Session`. Validate `$null -ne $session`. Validate command using `Try-Catch` around `Get-Command`

Comment: you could create a Scheduled task or Powershell scheduled task or job that does a one time run elevated as admin that could carry out this command.

Comment: @xwpedram can you expand what you mean by “IIS does not allow you to run Windows processing” please?