# Code is working fine locally, but not execute after hosting

Tags: iis, .net-core

I am using dot net core 2.1.
when I execute local code **Process.Start("C:/Windows/notepad.exe");** it is working fine.
But when I hosted my code on IIS it is not working.
I already give all the permission.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Typical mistakes of not understanding session isolation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS7 does not start my Exe file by Process Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414514/iis7-does-not-start-my-exe-file-by-process-start)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the client machine's notepad, it's impossible. The process start will just open the server's nodepad.

Since the client side browser will just get the server's reponse which is the html codes and show it. The process start is running on the server-side not client side.

The reason why you could open the nodepad is the client and server is the same machine.

Comment: Can we run .py file which is on Client machine..?

Comment: No, you could only run javascript on the client machine. Let the server run some tool or exe on the client machine is not security.