# Is there a way to share a folder on Azure VM to public like a website?

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

Is there a way to let any user, accessing the website hosted on Azure server VM, access a folder on the same VM and run an exe placed there? The exe needs to run on the server as well as there are some installations on the server that are needed by the exe to run.
I know that I can give access and share folder to the users of the network but the target audience are the users regardless of whichever network and location they access the site and folder from.

Totally new to all this so please share any resources that might be helpful for me to learn as well.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, your website application code would be written to execute the binary on the server when a user clicks a button or accesses a particular URI. How this is implemented will depend on the web server and language you are using. There are also security considerations when you're enabling your web server to interact with the OS that is hosting it (to run the executable).

You'll probably have more luck finding a specific answer in a forum for your web server and language--this is not an Azure-specific issue.

An example of someone doing something similar with IIS: [IIS7 does not start my Exe file by Process Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414514/iis7-does-not-start-my-exe-file-by-process-start)

Comment: The exe needs to run on the server and the user needs to access that folder after performing certain actions on the website. Ideally, the link for that folder should be displayed to the frontend from where the user can click and open that. Its like sharing a folder via going to properties but should be shared to everyone, not just people of the network. I understand this design can be made better by making the website do all this, but due to certain technical reasons we have to go with this approach for now. Any suggestions on how I can get this or something similar done?